# What would be the best way to strip values from custom list elements?

Tags: apex, list

I have a custom list `list<ExistingAccountResult>` that contains the following values:

> ([accountid=00111111111w5YIQAY, includeinfunnel=true, masterid=11111111, salesforceaccountid=O-22222222, status=Active], [accountid=0011111111w5YIQAY, includeinfunnel=true, masterid=244444445, salesforceaccountid=O-2333335, status=Active])

In this case I have two elements, but my list may contain many more depending on the scenario. What would be the best way to get into each element in the list and only remove the first value (accountid=...) from each element?

I was thinking converting the list to a `list<String>` and then look at each element from the new list, and strip the value, but this does not seem like an efficient way to do this.

Comment: Why not use a simple `for` loop with an assignment statement? What is driving the complexity here?

Comment: I would question why do you have a list like this, what is the list actually supposed to contain? Accounts records?

Comment: I guess I was overthinking it. I just run though a loop and assigned each element to a string where I did the removal of characters, and then added to a new list of strings, and it seems to be working. Thanks

Comment: This appears to be a debug of a custom object. I'm not clear on why string manipulation comes into play. That approach is likely to yield poor performance. [Edit]ing this question to be clearer about what exactly you're trying to do could be helpful.